# Right-Border of div should have same hight as image

Tags: html, css

does somebody know why the border on the right side is a bit higher than the image? How can ensure that the border on the right side of the div has the same hight as the image?

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNPeLv

Code:

```
<div class="footer-widgets-2">
<img src="http://www.fertighaus-keitel.de/uploads/tx_7thsensegallery/Haus-Wiesenweg-Nacht_01.jpg" alt="Footer-Pic">
</div>

.footer-widgets-2 {
  width: 810px;
  border-right:1px solid #a3a3a3;
  padding-right:20px;   
  margin-right: 20px;   
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `display: block` to remove the small space on the image

Comment: By default `img` elements receive `display: inline-block` from the user-agent stylesheet, which is white-space aware, treating the image like a word in a block of text with some natural space around it. There are [various ways of dealing with it](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), but `display: block` works the best in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Vertically aligning the image to the middle will solve this.

```
img{vertical-align:middle;}
```